# Using .gemspec version in documentation/library/script

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rdoc

So, I've been writing a bunch of ruby gems recently, and one thing I would find convenient is to include the current version (as specified in the gemspec) in the `rdoc`-generated documentation for my libraries, and in the `OptionParser`-generated `--help` sections used by my scripts (which I'm distributing via gem).  Any way I can make it easy for my users to figure out which version of library/script they're currently using.

Is there any way I can access the version I specify in my gemspec from the ruby files in my `lib/` or `bin/` directories? That way, I don't have to update it multiple places at once - just in my gemspec.

Currently I generate my gemspecs by hand, I haven't jumped on the Rake train yet.  If I can't do what I want directly with only what rubygems gives me, would rake or another tool allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way, I don't think, because Rubygems is just an installation mechanism for Ruby libraries, which have no predefined notion of versioning.

However, possible workarounds could include using `Gem.loaded_specs` to find which gems have been loaded:

```
Gem.loaded_specs["mygemname"].version.to_s #=> "1.2.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [newgem](http://rubyforge.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=28119) gem - as it both generates appropriate directory layout and also a gemspec file (compatible with GitHub).